# Simple Prolog while loop always returns false?

Tags: while-loop, prolog

I have a simple Prolog program that prints all the values from X to 10.

```
print_(X) :- X <= 10, X1 is X + 1, write(X), print_(X1).
```

So for example print_(5) would return: 5 6 7 8 9 10 False.

However I would like it to return True at the end. I have tried all sorts, is there anyway of doing this?!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume you're code really has `X =< 10` not `X <= 10` (which would be a syntax error).

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it using a termination case that succeeds:

```
print_(X) :-
    X =< 10,
    X1 is X + 1,
    write(X), nl,
    print_(X1), !.
print_(X) :- X > 10.
```

Then you get:

```
| ?- print_(5).
5
6
7
8
9
10

yes
| ?-
```

Note that this solution, as well as the solution @larsmans presented, will succeed on cases like `print_(11).`, but just won't display any values.

---

**ADDENDUM**

@CapelliC presented a very concise solution which will present failure if the initial argument is out of range. Another option, using simple predicates might be:

```
print_(X) :-
    X =< 10,
    X1 is X + 1,
    write(X), nl,
    (print_(X1) -> true ; true).
```

The last line says, "I don't care whether the query `print_(X1)` succeeds or fails, I want to succeed and move on." The `print_/2` predicate, however, will fail if the argument is initially out of range.

This yields:

```
| ?- print_(5).
5
6
7
8
9
10

yes
| ?-
```

And:

```
| ?- print_(11).

no
| ?-
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the pitfall pointed out in mbratch answer, an alternative could be

```
print_(X) :- X =< 10, forall(between(X,10,N), write(N)).
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in another predicate that negates the result.

```
print_loop(X) :- \+ print_(X).
```